# Formulas used in compositor Mix node?

Tags: compositing-nodes, documentation

I'm trying to understand how the `fac` and `clamp` values are used in `Mix` compositor node:

[image]

E.g. in the simple case of mix/add, there are at least two possibilities for adding invidual pixels, the red channel could be computed as `r1 * (1-fac) + r2 * fac` as well as `r1 + r2 * fac`. Similarly `clamp` could apply to `r1` and `r2` or `r`, and could be a simple `min(value, 1)` or some more complex scaling function and could either apply to individual pixels or to a value rescaling of the whole image.

[Blender documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/color/mix.html#properties) just indicates details can be found in Gimp documentation... [which in turn says](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html) for `add`:

> Addition mode is very simple. The pixel values of the upper and lower layers are added to each other. The resulting image is usually lighter. The equation can result in color values greater than 255, so some of the light colors may be set to the maximum value of 255.

It doesn't even mention the use of a weighting factor, this is confusing. However [this source](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/compositor/operations/COM_MixOperation.cpp) might be the one used for RBG values computation in Blender. From it I'd would assume:

- `mix` mode uses `r = r1 * (1-fac) + r2 * fac` according to [this method](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/compositor/operations/COM_MixOperation.cpp#L244).
- `add` mode" uses `r = r1 * + r2 * fac`according to [this method](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/compositor/operations/COM_MixOperation.cpp#L98).

And it seems the alpha channel of the first image is reused for the result for most of the modes. This also contradicts Gimp documentation which states for `Add`:

> The mode is commutative; the order of the two layers doesn't matter.

What about the `clamp` factor? More generally is there a corresponding and easier to read exhaustive documentation about blending modes for the compositor?